# Как получить id из другого компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form

Есть код:

```
class TodoTask extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.tasks.forEach((currentValue, index) => {
          <li key={index}>
            {currentValue}
            <button type="submit" id={index} onClick={this.props.click}>Delete</button>
          </li> 
        })}  
      </ul>  
    );
  }
}
```

Нужно в другом компоненте получить `id` нажимаемой кнопки, я хочу сделать это в строке:

`tasksArray: e.tasksArray.splice(id, 1)`

Как правильно получить `id` наживаемой кнопки из другого компонента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить простым способом через событие [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event), так как аттрибут `id` уже был заполнен, то не составит особого труда получить его значение. Пример кода:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tasks: ['first', 'second', 'third'],
    };
  }

  onButtonClick(event) {
    console.log('id:', event.currentTarget.id);
    alert(`Was clicked id: ${event.currentTarget.id}`);
  }

  render() {
    const { tasks } = this.state;

    return (
      <ul>
        {tasks.map((currentValue, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            {currentValue}
            <button type="submit" id={index} onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Delete</button>
          </li> 
        ))}  
      </ul> 
  )}
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

P.S.: переделал [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) на [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), так как использование `forEach` здесь не уместно.

> [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) -  элемент, в котором в данный момент
>   обрабатывается событие, при движении события внутри DOM. Всегда
>   совпадает с текущим элементом, в отличие от свойства [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/target),
>   идентифицируещее элемент, на котором событие возникло.

*P.S.: `event.currentTarget` используется, когда один и тот же обработчик события присваивается нескольким элементам.*

Answer (score 0):

Если id определяется с помощью index то и передавайте index в колбэк:

```
<button type="submit" id={index} onClick={()=>this.props.click(index)}>Delete</button>
```

Comment: Использование стрелочной функции в `render()` создаёт новую функцию при каждой отрисовке компонента, что не очень хорошо. Для ознакомления: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render